# Bootstrap "img-responsive" isn't working in my code why?

Tags: html, css

I want to make a logo responsive, so I have added `img-reponsive` and `col-xs-12` in the `img` tag class and also specified `width: 100%` in the external stylesheet but it is not working.

I have made logo right side and it comes in a laptop but is not visible in mobile phones so I have added  `img-responsive` in `<img>` and specified `width: 100%` and `height: auto;` for `img-responsive` in an external stylesheet and I have also specified `@media` but its the same

```css
#logo {
    padding-left: 380px;
    width: auto;
    height: 30%;
    position: fixed;
    float: right;
    border-bottom: 25px;
    padding-bottom: 25px;
    display: inline-block;
    top: -1em;
}
@media(max-width:568px) {
    #logo{
        float: right;
        padding-left: 300px;
        width: inherit;
        height: inherit;
        position: fixed;
    }
}
@media(max-width:767px) {
    #logo{
        float: right;
        padding-left: 200px;
        width: 100%;
        height: auto;
        position: fixed;
    }
}
.img-responsive{
    display: block;
    max-width: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    height: auto;
}
```

```html
<nav class="navbar navbar-default navbar-fixed-top d-flex">
    <div class="container">
        <div id="nav">
            <img src="images/logo.jpg" id="logo" class="img-responsive col-xs-12" />
        </div>
    </div>
</nav
```

Comment: Try the `img-fluid` class.

Comment: What version of Bootstrap are you using? In Bootstrap v4. `.col-xs-12` means **nothing**. Use `col-12` instead. Besides, ***always*** wrap `col-*` inside `.row`s or `.form-row`s. Without it you'll mess up the margins and get horizontal scrollbars, (your cols end up bigger than their parent on some screen widths).

Comment: Well i am using bootstrap 3 and after your response i tied linking with bootstrap4 and changed it to img-fluid and col-12 , but few things messed up and logo is'nt visible yet

Answer (score 0, accepted):

if you use bootsrap v4 you should know that img-responsive was changed to img-fluid and col-xs-12 was changed to col-12 you can see site documentation [Bootstrap V4.2 docs](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/getting-started/introduction/)

Comment: HI Bhumika, this is example of the responsive image code https://jsfiddle.net/fawzyzayed/atrvubh5/8/

Answer (score 0):

[Bootstrap img-fluid](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.2/migration/#images) img-responsive was changed to img-fluid

Answer (score 0):

Did you try removing padding-left:200px; from mobile media query also with position:fixed; float:right is not a good practice and need to use img-fluid instead img-responsive.

Comment: https://codepen.io/piyush11388/pen/RvZgXM here is working example you can see but if you can share the image how you want the logo will be good because i don't understand why you need padding-left here